# Alchemy getOwnersForCollection missing some owners

Tags: alchemy

Using the Alchemy API and getOwnersForCollection endpoint on Optimism, the returned list seems to be missing some holders despite those addresses having a balance for that collection. Here is the code to reproduce this example where a list is returned, and when an address that is verified to have that ERC-721 token in it is not found in the ownerAddresses response json.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = f"https://opt-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/nft/v2/demo/getOwnersForCollection?contractAddress=0xB8Df6Cc3050cC02F967Db1eE48330bA23276A492&withTokenBalances=false"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()['ownerAddresses'], columns=['address'])

verified_holder = '0xD968ACed4811a6072B537DB2F7e31851beeD0AD6'
df[df['address'].str.contains(verified_holder)] # no results found for verified holder
```